# refactor a regular for loop into an enhanced for loop

Tags: java

I have a *regular* `for` loop that helps me append a character by taking advantage of the index positioning provided by the common `for` loop.

I want to refactor the loop and turn it into a `for each` loop, but the disadvantage is the index positioning. I can't find a way to indicate where I want to append my char. Is it even possible to use the `for each` loop in this case?

**from:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < itinerary.size(); i++) {
    sb.append(itinerary.get(i).toUpperCase());
    if (i < itinerary.size() -1) {
        sb.append(" to ");
    }
}
```

**to**

```
for (String itineray : itinerary){
    sb.append(itineray.toUpperCase());
    if ( //size of the array - 1){
        sb.append(" to ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need an actual answer to your question about for-loops, or do you just want to know a better way to write your code, which is to use a [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)?

Comment: StringJoiner its a different class, im using StringBuilder.

Comment: I know you are using a `StringBuilder` in your question, but you can just write `iternary.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" to "))` and completely avoid the for loops.

Comment: What type of collection is `itinerary` ?

Comment: Looks like an `ArrayList` because the OP is using `get`

Comment: that's way out of my league...for now. This part of a class assignment, i've learned about for loop and enhanced for loop.

Comment: Just append `" to "` every time and then remove the last one after the `for loop`

Comment: what method of the class could i use for that action?

Comment: Yeah, I guess if it is a class assignment the instructor might not expect you to use streams. Welcome to Java. It's just `itinerary.join(' to ')` in JavaScript, and perhaps most other high-level languages. :/ Hang in there, it gets more fun post-Java :)

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to iterate over a subset of the original list which excludes the final element.  Then do one additional append afterward.

```
for (String itineray : itinerary.subList(0, itinerary.size()-1)) {
    sb.append(itineray.toUpperCase());
    sb.append(" to ");
}

sb.append(itinerary.get(itinerary.size()-1).toUpperCase());
```

Note that from a performance point of view, this should behave similarly to using an explicit `for` loop.  The only difference is the initial subsetting of the list, but after which point the enhanced loop can run without performing any index checks.  And the final append outside the loop would have to happen in any case.

But as @RayToal pointed out, you could use this and avoid the boundary condition problem altogether:

```
itinerary.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" to "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to convert to a String and use replace

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add ("one");
    list.add ("two");
    list.add ("three");

    String output = list.toString();
    output = output.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", " to");
    System.out.println(output);
```

**Output**

> one to two to three

Comment: It is possible for a string element to contain a comma.

Comment: @RayToal Not in my code ;-)  Also could contain the word ` to ` which woulc really confuse things

Comment: I'm sure the OP is looking for a _general_ solution to the problem. Yes if the list contains only strings with out brackets and commas, your expression with the three replaces will work, but this kind of approach causes huge security problems. It is the kind of thinking behind SQL injection and all sorts of attacks. But great point about the `"to"`!!! That's absolutely right! Don't know how to get around _that_ one. :)

Comment: If the OP is looking for a robust solution, then there is nothing wrong with his `regular for loop` and due to our concerns then I don't think it can be be beaten.  However if he is just doing a homework task, then knowing *Another way* has some benefit